# Disqus comment count only showing on first instance

Tags: disqus

I'm using the universal comment code from Disqus to show the comment count on my blog index e.g.

Displays the 10 latest posts, this is generated from a single template, so all the code etc, is replicated/looped through, so I wonder why only the first blog post in the results list is the only one showing the comment count (others are just blank e.g. it doesn't even say 0 comments)

I've tried using:

```
<a href="http://urlofpage.com/blog/article/title-here/#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="title-here_1_identifier"></a>
```

Where the number in the identifier matches the post ID, so that all get's generated fine

I've also assigned a unique identifier to the embed code on the page, just seems a strange bug to me, hope someone can help.

Seems strange, that the count works fine for the first blog post in the list, but for the others, it shows absolutely nothing...

Comment: Really hard to say without a real example, but usually it only happens like this on really inactive sites where certain threads wouldn't have even been created. Update with full source or an example page and we might be able to figure out more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment, turns out after 3 hours they appeared, must be a delay in updating the count. Cheers.